# Find the most common substring in an array of strings with a given sequence length

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sequence

I hope all is well on your end!

I encountered an interesting sequence problem and I've been struggling to solve it: "Find the most common sequence across the array of strings with a specific number of characters."

Input: `(["abc", "usbc", "bcde"], 2)`
Output: `"bc"`

Input: `(["terrific, specific"], 4)`
Output: `"ific"`

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function commonSubstring(array, length) {
  let popular = '';
  let seq = []
  let map = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      const str = array[i].slice(j, j+length)
      if (str.length === length && array[i].includes(str)) {
        seq.push(str)
      }
      if (array[i].includes(seq[j]) && !map[seq[j]]) {
        map[seq[j]] = 1
        // console.log(seq[j])
      } else {
        map[seq[j]]++
        j++
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(map)
  return popular
}
```

What I was trying to do is go through each string element and find common sequences and I added a map to have a point system, then ultimately find the key that has the most points and return that key.

Honestly, I'm a bit lost. How do I efficiently solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Just shorten your inner loop to `for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length - length + 1; j++)` and I don't think that you need the `.include(..)` and length checks after that.  Other than that I'm not sure there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Also, that last `j++;` towards the end doesn't look right.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, thank you! I will look into it. Just curious, how would you approach this kind of problem?

Comment: Same as you did.  I have posted my version of your code with my changes as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution using a for loop and recursive call

```js
const getSequence = (list, length, check) => {
  if(!list.length || (check && check.length < length)) {
   return false;
  }
  let result = check || list[0];  //setting first item as a result
  let found = true;

  let i;
  for(i = 1; i<list.length; i++) {
    if(list[i].indexOf(result.substring(0, length)) == -1) {
      found = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found) {
     let val = getSequence(list, length, result.substring(1, result.length)) //calling same function by removing first char 
     if(val) {
      return val;
     }
  }
  else {
    return result.substring(0, length);
  }
}


console.log(getSequence(["abc", "usbcj", "bcdeh"], 2))
console.log(getSequence(["terrific", "specific"], 4))
console.log(getSequence(["test", "text"], 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't think of using recursive but this is great. For algorithms like these, how would you calculate the space and time complexity? Thanks!

Comment: it depends on how many loops you are running. i have managed to reduce the complexity, that's why I am breaking the loop when the value doesn't match in the first element. and also returning false on the start of function on some condition

Comment: And the complexity of this method is O(m*(n-x)) m is the length of the array and n is length of the first string in array, x is the length given, this must be the lesser complexity one. because it will only run a lesser number of loops. your method will run n*n of loops which might be higher in complexity. so I prefer recursive calls. Note: (I am not good in calculating complexity, it would be appreciated  if anyone can verify this)

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of your code that implements the suggestions in my comment above:

- Shorten the inner (j) loop to only loop through offsets that can hold the length in the current string,
- Remove the length checks, as they are no longer needed,
- Remove the checks for the substring in the array as they are unneeded.

I also added the max-search so that it would return the answer:

```js
function commonSubstring(array, length) {
  let popular = '';
  let seq = []
  let map = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length - length + 1; j++) {
      const str = array[i].slice(j, j+length)
      if (!map[str]) {
        map[str] = 1
      } else {
        map[str]++
      }
    }
  }
  // console.log(map)
  
  let maxv = 0;
  for(let prop in map) {
    if(map[prop] > maxv) {
      popular = prop;
      maxv = map[prop];
    }   
  }
  return popular
}

console.log(commonSubstring(["abc", "usbcj", "bcdeh"], 2))
console.log(commonSubstring(["terrific", "specific"], 4))
console.log(commonSubstring(["test", "text"], 2))
```

This runs in `O(n*m)` where `n` is the total number of input characters and `m` is the length parameter. As far as I know this is the best CPU complexity you can get for this problem.  As for implementation efficiency, this should be pretty close to the best possible.

Comment: Note: I made it a runnable snippet and fixed some typos.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I was kind of close. I can see where I went wrong. Again, thank you! I really appreciate it.